# Proper way to have 2 requests between client and server

Tags: c#, grpc

I have an P2P network app which acts as a server and client.

The app connects to multiple clients in a mesh and sends "data" to each other once the data has been processed.

If a client gets an incoming request then creates their own request before completing the incoming request it seems to deadlock and neither requests complete. Everything works fine unless a create is sent which processing one.

Is this because I'm not using `async` on the server methods or is this because I shouldn't send a request while processing one?

proto

```
rpc submit_data(DataSubmission) returns (DataSubmissionAck);
```

RPC Server

```
public async void Start()
{
    _server = new Server()
    {
       Services = {
          DataService.BindService(new DataService())),
       },
       Ports = { new ServerPort(_IpAddress, _Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
    };

    _server.Start();
}
```

Client method

```
public void SubmitData(Data data)
{
    ...
    var serverResponse = _serviceClient.submit_data(request);
    ...
}
```

Server method

```
public override Task<DataSubmissionAck> submit_data(DataSubmission request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    DataSubmissionAck clientResponse = new DataSubmissionAck();
    return Task.FromResult(clientResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to have worked is making the server and client-side calls all `async`.